# MySQL/PHP Only Returning One Result

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have seen a few topics like this so i would like to say sorry first but none of the solutions given in those topics fixed my issue.

I am trying to make a dynamic navigation menu using php and mysql, i have multiple inputs in the database as dummy text but for some reason it only wants to show one result..

Here is my code:

```
<?php 
require_once("../includes/connect.php");
include("../includes/header.php");
include("../includes/functions.php"); 
?>
    <div id="content">
        <table id="table">
            <tr>
                <td id="nav">
                    <ul class="info">
                        <?php 
                            $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM information LIMIT 10", $connection);

                            while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
                                echo "<li>{$row["menu"]}</li>";
                            $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM pages WHERE information_id ={$row["id"]} LIMIT 10", $connection);
                                echo "<ul class=\"pages\">";
                            while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
                                echo "<li>{$row["menu"]}</li>";
                            }
                                echo "</ul>";
                            }
                        ?>
                    </ul>
                </td>
                <td id="main">
                    <h2>Main Content</h2>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
    <?php 
    include("../includes/footer.php"); 
    ?>

</body>
</html>
```

Dont hate because there are tables in here lol, its not for public use and i will be converting it to grids when i get it all set up and functioning. I am not a 'pro' php programmer so be nice!

Comment: you might want to name your fetch/result/row variables differently for the while loop iteration.

Comment: Oh my, i am so dumb. I worked out the issue, i used the variable $result for both queries. I changed the second $result to $res and its working fine now... sorry! thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the problem is here..

your are pushing datas to the same variables twice....

make first query and push to $result. again make another query and push datas to same var $result.

try pushing it to seperate variable

```
 $result1 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM pages WHERE information_id ={$row['id']} LIMIT 10", $connection);
                            echo "<ul class=\"pages\">";
                        while ($row1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
                            echo "<li>{$row1["menu"]}</li>";
                        }
```

Comment: Haha yeah, i just saw that! Thanks! Why does it seem weird?

Comment: weird as in like i think you can use join instead of two loops.. anyways since i have no idea how your table structure is so i assume your are doing it right... removed the weird part..:).. anyways glad it helped.. happy coding... CHEERS!!! :)

Comment: Haha oh right ok lol. Well like i said, im not a pro and im working on improvements :) - Im sure i will end up recoding it to what you just stated in the near future when i boost my skills up :D